# Angular - Async call

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

In my app, I'm calling a service :

```
getEnv(): Promise<string>{
        return this.http.get(this.url + 'Home/GetEnv')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().environment)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

to return to a component

```
getEnvironnement(): string {

      this.appService.getEnv().then(url => {
          this.url = url;
      })  

      return this.url;
  }
```

The problem is the following. When I'm calling `MyComponent.getEnvironnement()`, the result is `undefined`, because the call to my service is async, I know all this stuff. But.. Is there a way to wait before returning `this.url` ?

Thanks !

Comment: If you wait for this operation, for example it takes 2 minutes to complete the http request, what would your user be doing in this time period? There's a reason why we have async operations in front-end world, you should embrace it.

Comment: Ok. So how can I return this.url ?

Comment: You don't/can't. You set the field `url` on the component, that's it.

Comment: Where are you going to use it?

Comment: @AlexCaron Small note tangential to the question. You probably shouldn't be both setting `this.url` and returning it in the same function, although I don't know enough about your code to understand what you're doing. In general, mutating things in asynchronous code is a recipe for a difficult to understand program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to write your code in a sequential style, while still retaining the benefits of non-blocking async HTTP requests:

```
async getEnvironnement(): Promise<string> {
  this.url = await this.appService.getEnv();
  return this.url;
}
```